# Use data from a related collection inside a Meteor #each

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, spacebars

I have a collection of People that has the fields {name, id}

I also have the field Likes that contains {user_id, foodName}

I want to create a template that will display a list of People, and the food they like. I am running an *each* in my template to pull all of this information from a query on the Likes collection. I want to take the queried user_id from Likes and then use it to pull the associated name of the person from the People collection.

My template looks like this:

```
<template name="likes">
  {{#each likes_list}}
    //This displays the user_id, but I want to have it display the user's name
    <p>{{user_id}} likes {{foodName}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

My helper looks like this:

```
Template.likes.helpers({  
  likes_list: function() {
    return Likes.find();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions:

1. Add `userName` filed to your `Likes` collection and display it like
   this `{{userName}}` in your template
2. Create publish function which will "join" your collections (Users and Likes). To do it use this package: https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper to return the user data context and then use it with `with`:

html:

```
<template name="likes">
  {{#each likes_list}}
    <p>{{#with person}}{{name}}{{/with}} likes {{foodName}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.likes.helpers({  
  likes_list: function() {
    return Likes.find();
  },
  person: function(){
    return People.findOne({id: this.user_id});
  }
});
```

Comment: I think it's `Meteor.userId()` on the client

Comment: He specified that he has a collection of *People* with `id` instead of `_id` so I was following his case literally. If the *People* collection is actually *Meteor.users* then it's an easy modification.

Comment: I should have been more specific. Ultimately, I want this functionality to work with the accounts-facebook package.

Comment: @MichelFloyd How would I change the above code to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You could map it into a single object if you wanted to.

```
Template.blah.helpers({
  likes: function () {
    return Likes.find().map(function (doc) {
      return _.extend(doc, {
        user: Meteor.users.findOne(doc.user_id)
      });
    });
  }
});
```

This will add the `user` field to the collection for you to reference

```
{{#each likes}}
  {{user.name}} likes {{foodName}}
{{/each}}
```